Sun Dome after roof reinstall
Recently ,roof was reinstalled( reinstall underlayment)
I think that this Sun dome might not be re-installed correctly.
Is it correct?



Why do you think it's incorrectly installed?

The rectangular black covering the dome is on tile. Shouldn't it be under concrete tile?

The flashing is above the tile, and as long as it extends below the uphill tile that's good. Can't tell from your pictures. Otherwise water hitting the dome would run under the tile.

There is no way of knowing if the installation is done correctly by looking at pictures on top of the roof.
The tile is not waterproof. What protects your home is the coating under the tile. There are a few different methods called the secondary water resistance. (SWR)  This is where the tube needs to be sealed.
The flashing on top is a good idea. However it should not be the singular method of keeping rain out.
